# Component GUID in Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have a .net dll that is shared by 2 applications of mine, client and the server.

I do not know where the files will be installed as user chooses the install and he may only install client or both client and server.

I have component on both server and client wix and it contains only the shared assembly.

Should I have same GUID for both of them? Does installing both server and client on the same path impact the install in any way? Server and Client may want different assembly versions but filename would be same.

Comment: Maybe check my answer on when component guids should change here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the server and client would want two different assembly versions, then you'll have to have two different DLL's and, hence, you'll need two different GUIDs (not sure why you would need a different assembly).

If that is not the case, though, you can still determine the location of the DLL (even if the user installs to another location).  For example, you could always put the DLL in a predetermined location (the system32 folder for example) and you'll then be guaranteed to have it there no matter where they do the rest of the install.  Or, you could set an environment variable which points to the location of the DLL.

I would recommend the second approach and use only one GUID.  It doesn't seem like there is a compelling reason for two separate DLLs.