# When I create a new setup project it tells me that the GUID syntax is is not correct

Tags: wix

I just installed WIX 3.11 in VS Community 2017 and when I created a new installation project I got a message saying that the syntax of the GUID is not correct. I do not know where I should supply this.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Short Answer***: Use **UPPERCASE GUIDs** like this: **`{F77F1880-CBDE-42CD-A45E-9D9C990BC3C2}`** - for attributes that require a valid GUID. They include several things such as **`Product Code`**, **`Upgrade Code`**, **`Package Code`** (auto-generated) and **`Component GUIDs`**. Use the **Create GUID tool** to make GUIDS. In the Visual Studio menus: **`Tools`** **`=>`** **`Create GUID`**. See screenshot below.

***Notes***:

- The braces at each end of the GUID: **`{`** and **`}`** are optional.
- WiX will handle lowercase GUIDs as well, but MSI will not (the finished MSI must have UPPERCASE GUIDs). Just use UPPERCASE GUIDs and you are done.
- You can use a **`*`** for some attributes to auto-generate a GUID at compile time. For example the product code.
- [For component GUIDs you can leave out the whole attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965).

---

***Quick Start***: Step-by-step description of how to compile a [**"WiX Hello World-style MSI"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615). The inline comments in the actual markup at the bottom is probably enough to get you going. [And a similar Hello World sample from CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with).

***General Tips***: And here are some: [**WiX Quick-Start Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). Particularly the Sample WiX Code towards the bottom might be helpful.

***WiX Help File***: The WiX help file has a piece on this: [How To: Generate a GUID](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/generate_guids.html).

---

***GUID***: [A GUID is a globally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) for example this one: **`{273323D2-5845-4517-8131-5458A065F06E}`**. I guess that is clear? If not please read the link. It is a **`128-bit number`** expressed in various flavors.

- There are many flavors of GUIDs, and the ones you can use in WiX are easily created using the **Create GUID tool** included with Visual Studio (In the menus: **`Tools`** **`=>`** **`Create GUID`** - see screen shot below).
- Alternatively you can use a web site for the purpose such as [**Online GUID Generator**](https://www.guidgenerator.com/).

***The Create GUID Tool***

[image: Create GUID Tool]