# After making wintoolset NOT delete files after an uninstall, how do make them uninstallable again?

Tags: c#, wix

I used the following code to make a file NOT get deleted during an uninstall:

```
  <Condition Level="0">
    <![CDATA[REMOVE = "ALL"]]>
  </Condition>
```

But I guess since I put it in the same  which has the  of some other files, it made the other files Not uninstallable as well.

```
<Feature Id="Config_File" Title="Configuration File" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponents" />
  <ComponentRef Id="Executable" />     
  <ComponentRef Id="Config_File" />
  <Condition Level="0">
    <![CDATA[REMOVE = "ALL"]]>
  </Condition>
</Feature>
```

...
I also had set the Permanent tag to "yes" for the file I wanted to NOT get deleted during an uninstall:

```
<Component Id="Config_File" Guid="*" Permanent="yes" NeverOverwrite="yes">
   <File Id="ApplicationConfigFile" Name="application.config" Source=".\application.config" Vital="yes" />
</Component>
```

My question is: how do I make these files uninstalable again?

- setting "Level" in the Condition to "0" didn't work either.
- setting "permanent" to "no" didn't work.

  ```
      <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
      <!--MediaTemplate /-->

  <Media Id="1" Cabinet="SOPHATEL_Server_Management.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

      <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SOPHATEL Server Management" Level="1">
          <!--ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" /-->
    <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponents2" />
    <ComponentRef Id="Executable" />     
      </Feature>
  <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />
  ```

  ```
  <Fragment>
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
          <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
              <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SOPHATEL Server Management" />
          </Directory>
      </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

    <Component Id="ProductComponents" Guid="f5207608-9c81-4317-89de-061066ec863c">
      <File Id="WebAPISelfHostingExe" Name="WebAPISelfHosting.exe" Source="..\WebAPISelfHosting\bin\Debug\WebAPISelfHosting.exe" Vital="yes" />
    </Component>

    <Component Id="ProductComponents2" Guid="f5207608-9c81-4317-89de-061066ec863d" NeverOverwrite="yes">
      <File Id="configFile" Name="application.config" Source=".\application.config" Vital="yes" />
    </Component>

    <!--Component Id="icon.ico" Guid="7805267a-624b-41e7-baaf-49b82c0439cc">
      <File Id='icon.ico' Name='icon.ico' Source="..\WixInstall\icon.ico" KeyPath='yes' />
    </Component-->

    <Component Id="Executable" Guid="f5207608-9c81-4317-89de-061066ec863e">
      <File Id="Service_testExe" Name="Service_test.exe" Source="..\Service_test\bin\Debug\Service_test.exe" Vital="yes" />
      <!-- Remove all files from the INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
      <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />
      <!-- Remove INSTALLFOLDER on uninstall -->
      <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLDIR" On="uninstall" />
      <!-- Tell WiX to install the Service -->        
      <ServiceInstall 
      Id="ServiceInstaller" 
      Type="ownProcess" 
      Name="Service_test" 
      DisplayName="Service_test"
      Description="A Test Service that logs dummy text on an interval to a text file." 
      Start="auto" 
      ErrorControl="normal" />
      <!-- Tell WiX to start the Service -->
      <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="Service_test" Wait="yes" />

  </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
  ```

All files are NOT uninstallable now, I want to be uninstallable again.

Comment: Don't have much time. The easiest would probably be to change the main installation directory, generate new component GUIDs (or use [auto-guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965)), use one file per component and only set the file you want permanent to be installed by a component marked with the permanent flag. The new installation folder path has to do with [the component rules, key paths and breaking the link to the sins of the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121).

Comment: Changing the GUID worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Are you using major upgrades with early uninstall of old version? (as in location of RemoveExistingProducts in the InstallExecuteSequence)

Comment: I am not using RemoveExistingProducts or InstallExecuteSequence at all, all I have is: 
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
But I do have this issue resolved, thank you.

Comment: This issue is more complicated than you think and affects future updates, but maybe you are not live yet?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the GUID worked for me.  I put in a new GUID, and the files now can be uninstalled.