# PYRO0305 - Removing component 'cmp_GUID_HERE' from feature 'OnlineHelpFeature' is not supported. (WiX Toolset v3.11)

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm struggling for a few days to solve an issue with pyro.exe (**WiX Toolset v3.11**)

My log file basically contains thousands of error messages like the following:
H:\Deployment\Products\Blow\obj\x64\Release_BlowHelp_CGroup_dir.wxs(12458) :

**error PYRO0305** : 
*Removing component 'cmpA4B66597F4A2A840FB4A84DB1681D5FB' from feature 'OnlineHelpFeature' is not supported. 
Either the component was removed or the guid changed in the transform 'H:\I\BlowPatch.wixmst'. 
Add the component back, undo the change to the component guid, or remove the entire feature.*

**The batch file we're using to cook a patch (.msp file) is:**

REM **CANDLE.EXE**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe" BlowPatch.wxs -out F:\I\BlowPatch.wixobj
```

REM **LIGHT.EXE**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe" F:\I\BlowPatch.wixobj -out F:\I\BlowPatch.wixmsp
```

REM **MELT.EXE, STEP 1/2**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Melt.exe" "H:\\Product_Releases_6.0\PreRelease\6.1.18230.1\Blow\bin\x64\Release\en-US\BlowServer_6.1.18230.1.msi" -out F:\M\Blow_6.1.18230.1\Blow_6.1.18230.1.wixpdb -pdb "H:\\Product_Releases_6.0\PreRelease\6.1.18230.1\Blow\bin\x64\Release\en-US\BlowServer_6.1.18230.1.wixpdb" -x F:\M\Blow_6.1.18230.1
```

REM **MELT.EXE, STEP 2/2**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Melt.exe" "H:\\Product_Releases_6.0\PreRelease\6.1.18231.1\Blow\bin\x64\Release\en-US\BlowServer_6.1.18231.1.msi" -out F:\M\Blow_6.1.18231.1\Blow_6.1.18231.1.wixpdb -pdb "H:\\Product_Releases_6.0\PreRelease\6.1.18231.1\Blow\bin\x64\Release\en-US\BlowServer_6.1.18231.1.wixpdb" -x F:\M\Blow_6.1.18231.1
```

REM **TORCH.EXE**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\torch.exe" -p -xi "F:\M\Blow_6.1.18230.1\Blow_6.1.18230.1.wixpdb" "F:\M\Blow_6.1.18231.1\Blow_6.1.18231.1.wixpdb " -out F:\I\BlowPatch.wixmst
```

REM **PYRO.EXE**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\pyro.exe" F:\I\BlowPatch.wixmsp -t BlowPatch F:\I\BlowPatch.wixmst -out Rollup_6.1.18230.1_to_6.1.18231.1\Blow_Rollup_6.1.18230.1_to_18231.msp
```

I read a lot of articles saying removing these components is a violation but I just need to safely solve that issues since the guy that used to deal with WIX toolset are not working with us and I got this as a gift. 8-(

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks,
Wander

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to create a minor upgrade patch. These are renown for being limited and difficult to deal with - to the degree where it must be regarded as a technology anti-pattern. One of the limitations for a minor upgrade is that you are not supposed to remove any components from any features in the new version.

Rather than repeating the descriptions of all minor upgrade and patch limitations, please skim this answer: **[Is there any possible way to perform upgrade when Product codes for old and new versions are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441601/is-there-any-possible-way-to-perform-upgrade-when-product-codes-for-old-and-new/51444047#51444047)** I rarely use patching due to these restrictions.

Either you need to comply with these severe limitations, or you need to use a major upgrade to deliver your new version. I don't know the details of your application. How large is the package? What is the number of components and features? Does it use a lot of custom actions, etc...

I will have to call this an answer, but I will check back to see if you add any more details.