# How to rename the base file element name under component during hotfix using windows installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6, msi-patch

In base version of my setup, by mistakenly i added the same name for two files like:

```
<component id="x" GUID="guid value">
<file id="x" source="c:\files\x.dll" name="x.dll">
</component>
<component id="y" GUID="another guid value">
<file id="y" source="c:\files\y.dll" name="x.dll">
</component>
```

Now I want to change the name to "y.dll" for the file with id="y" using HotFix.

If we change the name directly, the compiler error has been thrown "Component "y" has a changed keypath in the transform 'C:\Patches\diff.wixmst'. Patches cannot change the keypath of a component.

Please suggest me know how to change the file name using hotfix?

Comment: Do you need to patch? I guess, since you call it a hotfix. I normally just change the installation folder or rename both files to "break the link to the sins of the past" :-). Then MSI sees two new files, and not the old ones. You can also leave out the id attribute for normal sources. Do you use a major upgrade or a minor upgrade? [Minor upgrades have many limitations and restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - I wrongly placed the x.dll file name to y.dll file name in component in MSI. Can I correct it using patch?