# Windows MSI package fails to install with error 1603 when its location on disk is different than the older version's

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I installed software using the MSI package stored in C:\tmp. Later I upgraded with a later version. The MSI package was copied to C:\Kevin and I ran this command to upgrade in quiet mode:

```
c:\windows\System32\msiexec.exe /i C:\Kevin\nis-320-1000-x64.msi /qn REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus IS_MINOR_UPGRADE=1 ALLUSERS=1
```

it failed with error 1603.

I moved the MSI package to C:\tmp and ran this command:

```
c:\windows\System32\msiexec.exe /i C:\tmp\nis-320-1000-x64.msi /qn REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus IS_MINOR_UPGRADE=1 ALLUSERS=1
```

It worked. Can anyone give me an explaination? Did I do anything wrong?
My server runs Windows Server 2012
On another server I started installing the software from C:\Kevin, then upgrade the software from C:\tmp and I got the same result. It looks like I have to put the MSI package at the same location I used to install the software at the beginning
It worked. Can anyone give me an explaination? Did I do anything wrong?
My server runs Windows Server 2012

Thanks!

Comment: Been too long since I have seen this kind of stuff, you need to get some logging going. [Logging how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130). See the hints for log interpretation in there too. Minor upgrades are quite restrictive. [I have this from before as a quick list of limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130). Might not be relevant.

Comment: The log file is too large to post.

Comment: Please see the link on logging, there is a section on interpreting the log. Search for "value 3" first - as described. People tend to post logs on github, pastebin or other sites like that.

Comment: One of the limitations of minor upgrades is that the MSI file name has to be the same. It shouldn't really work if you install from the same folder using a file with different name, but I guess it does. I don't really use minor upgrades - they are too restrictive.

Comment: I found the error. I installed is-6300-339.msi, then is-6300-340.msi. The installer tried to read C:\tmp\is-6300-339.msi which I stored in and installed from C:\Kevin. Of course the file is not there. Why does the installer behave this way? Thanks!