# Making changes to installed MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I will try to explain the issue by example. I have `mypackage-v1.0.msi` and `mypackage-v1.1.msi`. Both packages when installed silently expecting PASSWORD parameter:

```
msiexec /i mypackage-v1.0.msi /qb PASSWORD=SomeThing1
```

`mypackage-v1.0.msi` is already installed and `mypackage-v1.1.msi` should upgrade mypackage-v1.0.msi. There is a custom action in both packages that depends on this parameter but because of the issue with conditioning this custom action in mypackage-v1.0.msi, during upgrade it is executed but the PASSWORD parameter is not transferred to it.

I wonder if there is a way to patch mypackage-v1.0.msi before upgrading to mypackage-v1.1.msi. But the patch is not changing any contents of installation but the package itself. Is it possible?

Edit:
More focused input - is it possible with the patch to replace a condition for InstallExecuteSequence custom actions?[image: Reference to actions displayed in Orca]

Comment: It is not uncommon for packages to contain errors that cause upgrade problems. [Here are some approaches for dealing with installed packages that cause upgrade or uninstall problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876550/wix-custom-action-dialogbox-on-silent-uninstall-of-application/53876981#53876981). One option is to use a minor upgrade. These [minor upgrades have many limiations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130), but they allow you to upgrade a product "in-place" rather than uninstall and reinstall (which is what major upgrdes do and trigger problems in the process).

Comment: Thanks I will look into that.

Comment: Those approaches are for packages that fail to uninstall, but the use of minor upgrades can generally fix any errors in the installed package's uninstall sequence that manifest on uninstall or upgrade and cause the process to fail. In effect the minor upgrade "hotfixes" the uninstall sequence before it is called or invoked. Only approach 2 should be relevant for you in [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876981/129130).

Comment: I edited the question and added more focused question of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, you can change almost anything in the installed package. The simplest sample of a minor upgrade I could find at the moment is probably [this one](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/Patch). Open the `CreatePatch.cmd` and update path to WiX binaries (likely ending in v3.11 at this point in time). Keep in mind that a minor upgrade has [many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130). Keep things simple and change only what you need to fix your problem.

Comment: [See what needs to change for a minor upgrade in the table at the bottom here](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm) (package code and product version + plus whatever change you want to implement). You can deliver the minor upgrade as a new MSI or as a patch file (*.msp). For an MSI you need to use a special command line to install. Something like this: `msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL`. The `v` there tells msiexec to re-cache the MSI so that it updates the existing cached one "in-place".

Comment: See below for the above in answer form - too many messy comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Patches include transforms, which modify packages. In fact, patches always modify tables in the package, even when they don't change content of the payload files.

Comment: I added an explanation to the question of what I am trying to achieve. Will that be possible to do with the patch?

Answer (score 0):

The comments above became too messy. Here is a quick re-write as a regular answer:

---

***Minor Upgrade***: A minor upgrade can change most things in an installed MSI package before its uninstall or upgrade sequence is called. It can hence fix problems relating to major upgrades or failed uninstalls among other things (you fix the uninstall sequence before it is invoked).

***Sample***: [Here is the simplest sample of a minor upgrade](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/Patch) I could find at the moment ([another sample from FireGiant's documentation](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/patchwork/)).

- For the simple sample: open the `CreatePatch.cmd` and update path to WiX binaries (likely ending in v3.11 at this point in time: `set wixDir="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\"`).
- Keep in mind that [a minor upgrade has many limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130). Keep things simple and change only what you need to fix your problem.

***Minor Upgrade Details***: [The table at the bottom here](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm) shows what needs to change for a minor upgrade. Essentially **package code** and **product version** + **plus whatever change you want to implement**. The above link is to InstallShield's documentation (a different MSI tool), but this is a generic MSI technology concept - it is not vendor specific.

You can deliver the minor upgrade as a new MSI or as a patch file (*.msp). For an MSI you need to use a special command line to install. Something like this:

```
msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi REINSTALLMODE=vomus REINSTALL=ALL
```

The `v` tells msiexec to re-cache the MSI so that it updates the existing cached one "in-place".

- [REINSTALLMODE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/reinstallmode).
- [Applying Small Updates by Reinstalling the Product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/applying-small-updates-by-reinstalling-the-product).

---

***Links:***

- https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912367-Upgrade-options
- https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/