# Will change in ComponentID for component in Windows Installer effect during upgrade scenerio.?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, installshield

There is Product1 with Component1 of version 1.0.0.0. There is a Product2 with same Component of version 2.0.0.0 of which the Component ID (GUID) value is changed .
Now if we do the minor upgrade from Product1 to Product2 , will the component be updated from 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0 . Or will it remain same as the GUID value is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this old answer for more details: [**When to change component GUIDs?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422121/129130)

---

Component GUIDs should remain stable between releases unless you move the keyfile of the component to a new absolute location on disk (you move the file in your source hierarchy relative to your other files - target destination on disk can vary depending on where you install as base-folder - INSTALLDIR). In that case it is treated as a new file and should be given a new identity - which means a new component GUID.

The component GUID identifies a keyfile at a specific location, the GUID does not "follow the file around" if it moves to a different location on disk.

If the file remains stable on disk, the component ID does the work of reference counting and identifying the same file across releases.

---

***Links:***

- [Minor upgrades are know to have lots of limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130)
- [WiX Setup: When do I need to change the GUID of a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260553/wix-setup-when-do-i-need-to-change-the-guid-of-a-component/72263030#72263030)