# Overwrite an existing folder for a minor upgrade

Tags: wix

I am having an existing version of an installation which has a third party folder as a part of the installation.Now the third party keeps changing its versions and hence the folder contents also change with the versions. Some files from the existing version have been removed and do not exist anymore in the latest version

I am doing a minor upgrade and with this the old files do not get deleted and still remain under the folder.
I have changed the GUID of the component(not the component ID) associated with the installed folder as per below thread but it still does not work

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Removing-files-as-part-of-upgrade-td7600623.html

Please suggest.

Comment: Want to add that we get frequent updates or newer versions of the third party library which includes addition of new binaries and removal or renaming a few.

Comment: [Maybe have a look here first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924997/how-to-delete-files-from-installer-during-minor-upgrade).