# Wix custom action to execute only during install but not on upgrade and remove?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.11

I have a custom action that has to execute only during  install but not during minor release upgrade and remove?
I tried with different conditions but the CA is executing during minor release.

1) (NOT Installed) OR NOT(REMOVE="ALL" AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)

2) (NOT Installed)

3) (NOT Installed) OR NOT(Installed AND REMOVE="ALL" AND UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)

but nothing works for me. 
And my CA is executing twice may be because during upgrade the setup is uninstalling and installing.
Any suggestions how to execute CA only during install but not during upgrades.

Comment: Is this an immediate mode custom action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Please Test***: You could try with **`(NOT Installed) AND (NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED)`** as a first test ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937078/129130)), and then use the debugging approach below to test properly. No guarantees! Conditions are notorious.

- A commonly used way to test if you are running uninstall as a part of major upgrade is to use the [**`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgradingproductcode).
- You should be aware of [these issues with regards to **`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51090120/129130) - it might not behave as you would expect at face value.
- I suggest using **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** instead of **`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`** in the above condition to keep it as simple as possible. This is a WiX-specific property (**`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`** is a built-in MSI property).

> ***Top Tip***: MSI conditions are notoriously fiddly to get right. You can debug MSI conditions pretty efficiently by the approach described
> here: [How to execute conditional custom action on install and modify
> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370505/how-to-execute-conditional-custom-action-on-install-and-modify-only/52377800#52377800) (see bottom section - using VBScript message boxes and then
> run the setup in different modes).

***Minor Upgrades***: Please be aware that [minor upgrades are very limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444047/129130) - and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55252064/129130). Please review the restrictions to make sure you are aware of them and that you can release your software with them in mind. Also make sure to test repair and modify scenarios for the installer.

***Advice***: ***`Often it is better to use the launch sequence of the application to perform application configuration than relying on custom actions since they have complex sequencing, conditioning and impersonation issues`***.

Comment: I see that WIX v4 is coming, can we make this conditions more readable like, `IsNotInstalled`, `IsInstalled`, `IsMinorUpgrade`, `IsMajorUpgrade` something like that.
Because I currently try to find out what `NOT REMOVE = "ALL"` means ;-)
And you can internally map it to whatever.

Comment: Great, do try those VBScript message boxes to help debugging different installation modes. [There are many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51558767/existing-uninstaller-broken-during-upgrade-patch-msi#comment90165965_51566926).