# Wix V4 - CustomAction Condition only when updating

Tags: wix, custom-action, wix4

## Details of the problem:

I have an action that has to be executed when unistalling but not when updating the product to a new version.

I have defined the UpgradeVersion like this:

```
<UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="PREVIOUSFOUND"
                Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                Maximum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
```

and this is the Custom action and its Condition:

`<Custom Action="DOSTUFF" Before="RemoveFiles" Condition='(REMOVE="ALL") And (NOT PREVIOUSFOUND)'/>`

Despite this, the action still fires when running the .msi with a higher version (e.g.: 1.0.0 -> 1.0.1).

I've also tried defining the `PREVIOUSFOUND` property like this: `<Property Id="PREVIOUSFOUND" Secure="yes"></Property>` to no avail.

## What I was expecting:

I expected the action to run only when uninstalling from the Control Panel Apps & Features and not when updating the program to a higher version.

Comment: For now, [please read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666105/129130). Follow the links and check if this clarifies things for you. Throwing in [this old answer on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944773/129130).

Comment: Hello @SteinÅsmul, thanks for your help! I've started using `UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE` rather than the property I defined and it seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: [Use messageboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377800/129130) (section towards bottom) to determine if your conditions are set correctly by invoking different installation modes (install, uninstall, upgrade, patch, modify, self-repair, etc...) and observe the results.

Answer (score 2):

As per Stein's comment, I found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657334/wix-custom-action-to-execute-only-during-install-but-not-on-upgrade-and-remove/59666105#59666105).

So I changed my condition to `<Custom Action="DOSTUFF" Before="RemoveFiles" Condition='(REMOVE="ALL") And (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)'/>` and now the CustomAction is triggered correctly.