# How to make shortcuts and add an icon through wix toolset

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, installation, windows-installer

I got tired while dealing with `installshield` errors and limitations, so I searched for a better alternative to get stuck with `wix toolset v3.8`

I read that it is very good to make setup files , I tried it to make a setup for my win forms application , after searching and reading , I wrote and modified its code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="Fb Messages Stealer v1.0" Language="1033" 
         Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Karam Najjar" 
         UpgradeCode="GUID-HERE">
    <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" 
                 InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Newer version already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" 
             Title="Fb Messages Stealer v1.0" Level="1">
         <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />

     </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Fb Messages Stealer v1.0" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>

</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
   <Component Guid="*" >
     <File Source="$(var.FbMessagesStealer.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"></File>
   </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

It works and make a setup file ,, but I want to make a shortcut in desktop and in start menu in addition to adding an icon to it .
I searched a lot in the internet and tried many codes , can any one help me , I need to finish making a setup as early as I can , thanx in advance.

Comment: One more tip: [**Many attributes in Wix are now optional**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24769965/129130). This "**noise removal**" can make your source files **significantly shorter** and **easier to read**, and arguably **less error prone** and **easier to keep up to date** (changes in the linker and compiler propagate). Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick with Wix, it provides a lot more flexibility and once you get going it will be easier.

- Perhaps try [**this well known Wix tutorial**](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/).
- And also the actual [**Wix toolset documentation's how-to section**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/).
- [And this ad-hoc link heavy answer with WiX resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

Finally, and this is the best advice for a tinkerer: I use **dark.exe** (part of the Wix toolkit) to **decompile MSI files** compiled by Installshield and other tools. This means you can use Installshield to create an MSI with bells and whistles, and then decompile it to a wxs file and you can then copy and paste the relevant Wix code sections from the decompiled WXS to your main WXS. **This works very fast and is better than any tutorial**.

Other answers dealing more with the actual xml code:

- [Create shortcut to desktop using WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868499/create-shortcut-to-desktop-using-wix)
- [From MSI to WiX, Part 10 - Shortcuts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/20/from-msi-to-wix-part-10-shortcuts.aspx)

Comment: Nice tip on Dark