# Automatic way to update component code in InstallShield Basic MSI project

Tags: installshield, guid

I have InstallShield 2013 Basic MSI project 
Is there an automatic way using a tool or script to automatically update all component code in the project ?

Answer (score 2):

**First question**: why do you want to do that? A component GUID is set in stone for all absolute paths it references. See a description of this here: [Change my component GUID in wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix)

If you are familiar with **COM automation**, you should be able to automate the generation of new GUIDs in your project using the [Installshield automation interface](https://www.google.no/search?client=opera&q=installshield%20automation%20interface&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

There are only a few cases where such an operation is logical and valid. If you are looking to install the same product many times, you can check out **instance transforms**. I have no real experience with this - I dislike the concept, but here are some pointers:

- [Installing Multiple Instances with Instance Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Authoring Multiple Instances with Instance Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Configuring and Building a Release that Includes Multiple-Instance Support](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/MultipleInst-Builds.htm)
- [Multiple Instances Tab for a Product Configuration](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ProdConfigMultiInstancesTab.htm)

Comment: In the case of multiple instance installers,  any component that doesn't have a file as a key path has to have unique components for each instance transform.   This is a real annoyance and for my installers I typically give these components a file (any file... readme.txt)   to get around that limitation.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I wasn't aware of this. I dislike the whole instance transform concept, as I said in the answer.

Comment: I've done extensive work in this area and it's hard to understand at first but really cool when it all works.  I've also done situations where instance names are defined at install time and decisions about whether to upgrade an instance or install a new instance or made at install time.  It all has to be tailored to how the customer uses their software.  A pain to set up but really functional once working.

Comment: Don't ask me.  Patching and localization are two things I know very little about nor do I want to know anything about.