# Detect side by side installations?

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper

We want to introduce a managed bootstrapper application that detects our software products that are already installed on the target machine and then gives options to install, update, downgrade, repair and uninstall. This works well with using the same UpgradeCode in the packages.

Our issue is with side by side installations: The software is supposed to be allowed to be installed side by side if the version is not within the same “Major-Release”. Therefore, we planned to change the UpgradeCode with each new “Major-Release”.

Now the question: **What is the best way to detect the side by side installations, of packages that are not within the Bundle of the current Bootstrapper?** Or is there a better alternative to install side by side without changing the UpgradeCode?

Comment: No time to look at this, but a couple of links on the issue of side-by-side installations: **`1)`** [I want to install an MSI twice](https://serverfault.com/a/66999/20599), **`2)`** [Installing multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650897/installing-multiple-instances-by-different-msi-having-same-package-code). **``3)``** [How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file). **`4)`** [Find Product Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29937568/129130).

Answer (score 0):

The bundle handles upgrade both at the bundle and at the MSI level. The MSI level upgrade or side-by-side install is handled by how the MSI package is written and what Upgrade code it uses. From what I understand from your question, if the MSI has a new Major-Release then you want to do a side by side install and if not you want to do an upgrade.

1. The easiest solution that I can think of is to change your Bundle upgradecode when there is a Major-Release. But as always with side-by-side install this will complicate things and there will be multiple bundles with multiple upgrade codes that you will have to manage.

For example, you installed MSI 1.0.0.0 with bundle upgradecode "abc". When a new MSI 1.1.0.0 comes, you will use the same bundle with "abc" and do an install. This will uninstall the MSI 1.0.0.0 and install 1.1.0.0.

When the MSI 2.0.0.0 comes along you will change the bundle upgrade code, "xyz". This will install the new MSI 2.0.0.0 (provided they have changed the upgradecode within the MSI). Now at this point if you have a new MSI 1.3.0.0 you have to make sure to change your bundle upgradecode back to "abc" before you can install 1.3. Hope you got the gist of the issue/complexity that I am talking about. Side-by-side install is always a problem when you want to handle upgrades and given a choice I will stay away from it.

2. Now another option that you have is to handle multiple MSI releases within the same bundle. If you know the upgradecode of the new major release then you can do a [product search](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/productsearch.html) based on the Upgradecode and then decide whether you want to uninstall the existing version and install the new version or just upgrade the existing version.

   ```
   <util:ProductSearch Id="ProductSearch"
                       UpgradeCode="{ProductC_MSI_UpgradeCode_GUID}"
                       Variable="ProductInstalled"
                       Result="state"/>
   ```

You can use the variable ProductInstalled to check if that product/upgrade code is already present and then do the changes within your bundle accordingly.

Comment: This is kind of what I feared. I hoped there is something on higher level than the UpgradeCode.