# How can I install multiple instances of a Windows Service from an MSI file?

Tags: service, windows-installer

Have an MSI file with multiple Windows Services. Running the MSI file creates an instance of each service. However, I am unable to install another instance of each service (or one of the contained services).

Have tried a few suggestions online but they seem more suited for EXE files. have tried MSINEWINSTANCE but from my understanding, this requires a .mst file which we don't have or know how to create.

Ideally, create each service with a "_#' at the end (where # is instance of the service.

Comment: [**Please check this old answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650897/installing-multiple-instances-by-different-msi-having-same-package-code).

Comment: Thanks. We have solved this issue now.

Comment: What did you end u p doing? You can add your own answer and set as accepted.